# Windows command line - accessing of remote windows server folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I am logged in a Windows 7 and was trying to access the shared folder located in a Windows server 2008. I can successfully map the network drive with the URL:

```
\\\ServerName\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\ImportantFolders\Documents\
```

in Windows 7.

But, when i try to do the same operation on the server "ServerName" it fails. Moreover when trying to accees through dos DIR command,

```
 C:\> dir "\\\ServerName\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\ImportantFolders\Documents"
```

It returns `The network path is not found`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `C:>dir "\\ServerName\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\ImportantFolders\Documents"` (Mind the quotes)

Comment: @EugenRieck - thank you so much. I have another problem. When i try to  enter the command C:>dir "\\XX.XX.XX.XX\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\ImportantFolders\Documents" on Windows server XX.XX.XX.XX it returns 'The network path was not found'. Can you please help me in that too.

Comment: 1. What does `net view \\XX.XX.XX.XX` give? 2. Is the network sharing **client** service on the server running and firewall-excepted?

Comment: For net view: Shared resources at XX.XX.XX.XX

XX.XX.XX.XX

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

--------------------------------------
Users       Disk
The command completed successfully.

Comment: @EugenRieck - i am not sure about the 2 ?? How do i check?

Comment: The answer to 1. already tells us, that \\XX.XX.XX.XX\DavWWWRoot either doesn't exist or is not visible for the current user.

Comment: Thank you, i am sorry i am a nerd. I don't have any experience in this. So can you tell me how to grant access to the current user?

Comment: I am sorry. net view gives this:Shared resources at XX.XX.XX.XX

XX.XX.XX.XX

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

----------------------------------------
Users       Disk
The command completed successfully.

Comment: Navigate to the real folder, right click, properties, sharing -> allow access for current user. (Sorry, no windows here, reciting from memory)

Comment: But net view gives same result for both Windows 7 and Windows server. Then how can i access it on Windows 7 but not on Windows server?

Comment: Depending on the current user maybe?

Comment: Map the Drive for the needed User to an unused Drive Letter, using the path you specified, [like so](http://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/), then the user can use the drive by typing the drive letter you mapped the drive to, in the example the user would type S: in the command window

Comment: @ECarterYoung, thanks. I tried it but could not map the network drive on my Windows server. Error 53, Network path not found.

Comment: You need to double check the path in that case...

Comment: I just realized your Path has 3 \'s in front try my mapping link w/ only 2